# Почему приватные поля не видны из метода?

Tags: php, классы, private

Теории `ООП` везде имеет свои нюансы. В `PHP` я с этой теорией плаваю, подскажите, пожалуйста.

**Проблема:** метод `setCellValue` ругается, что неизвестен `$page`,
а я его инициализирую в конструкторе.

Вот мой код:

```
class excelRptBUHSERVER{
private $objPHPExcel;
private $objReader;
private $page;

private $querystrfromBD;
private $rowfromBD;

public function __construct($template, $activePage,$info=false){
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($template);
$page = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($activePage); 

if ($info) {
echo("BUHSERVER");
}
}

function __destruct() {

}
public function setCellValue($cell,$val){

$page->setCellValue($cell, $val);
}
public  function drawinPage(){

}

}

$rpt_all_equip = new excelRptBUHSERVER('PHPExcel/rpt_all_equip.xlsx', 0, true);
$rpt_all_equip->setCellValue("F6","test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к нестатическим свойствам и методам класса происходит через псевдо переменную `$this`. Например `$this->objPHPExcel`. На текущий момент у вас в конструкторе просто локальные переменные никак не связанные с классом. В методе `setCellValue` аналогично

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: спасибо за отклик . ```$this->$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$this->$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$this->$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($template);
$this->$page = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($activePage); 
``` я так должен сделать ?

Comment: да. внутри метода тоже.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: всё равно ругается на строчки в конструкторе ```$this->$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();``` не говоря уже о методе setCellValue  :)

Comment: а ну да, потому что внимательно посмотрите как я написал и как вы написали... про cellvalue вообще не знаю есть ли у page такой метод

Comment: да нормально я написал. вот вы писали : Обращение к нестатическим свойствам и методам класса происходит через псевдо переменную $this. Например $this->objPHPExcel. а вот я $this->$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); $page дело второе.

Comment: ну окей, тогда предлагаю вам открыть блокнот, скопировать мой вариант, вставить первой строчкой, потом скопировать ваш вариант и вставить под моим и сравнить

Comment: всё, увидил наконец и без блокнота ))) но однако - нелогично )))) спасибо, помогли.

Comment: все там логично, т.к. язык позволяет конструкции вида `$field = "x"` и обратиться к `$obj->$field`

Comment: @АндрейГуренков ну почему, есть логика, если в одном месте появляется доллар, то в других убирается, чтобы не захламлять....да и долларом обозначается переменная, что и указавает `$this`...... это как в английском "he planS" - на конце "s", однако при вопросе "what doeS he plan"  буква "s" перетекает во вспомогательное. слово  "does".  ...Как доп эффект можно делать так, как описал teran выше